# How to correctly resize children of customview

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view

I need a view (custom view called `DayView`) that stretches twice the height of the scrollView it's in. In this view, there are two nested views, one of which is another custom view. The custom views all extend from `RelativeLayout`.

The layout is like this:

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <!-- Is twice the size as scrollView, see code below -->
    <com.example.DayView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Should be same size as parent DayView -->
        <include layout="@layout/layout_dayplan_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <!-- Should be same size as parent DayView -->
        <com.example.BlockView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </com.example.DayView>
</ScrollView>
```

The two nested views (`include` and `BlockView`) should have the same height as the parent `DayView`.

In the `DayView`, I override the onMeasure to make it twice as large. This works: (see the '* 2' in the second to last row)

```java
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
    this.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(parentWidth, parentHeight * 2 ));
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

The `DayView` has the correct size, however, the two nested views don't strech along with the parent, but seem to use a `wrap_content` height layout rule.

**Question**

How can I make these two nested views take over the same height as the parent `DayView`?

Comment: Try after removing this line `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);`

Comment: @JimitPatel: That doesn't work, the window doesn't seem to be twice the size anymore, and the children aren't drawn at all.

Comment: then make `parentHeight * 2` and pass it to `setMeasuredDimension()` method. Use modified value everywhere. Also, remove `setLayoutParams()` and `super.onMeasure()`. Because I generally use `setMeasuredDimension()` method without other mentioned method and it works for me

Comment: I think you can even use `super.onMeasure()`. let me provide proper solution..

Answer (score 0):

You can try following methods

```
        int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) * 2;
        this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
        measureChildren(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

Here it is measuring children too. Maybe this can work

Comment: This doesn't work. Result is that the DayView acts like it's height is `wrap_content`, so it isn't twice the size of the scroll window anymore.